# How to highlight self-defined class in sublime text 3

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I am using sublime text 3 to code c++, and how to highlight self-defined class, struct, function in sublime text 3. 
Here is an example:
In class.h

```
Class MyClass()
{
   public:
      void func();
}
```

In class.cpp

```
void MyClass::func()
{
    cout << "My Class";
}
```

The function

```
 MyClass::func()
```

in

```
class.cpp
```

is not highlighted.   Is there a way to do syntax highlight this?